# How to know which NSCombobox selector calling the Delegate

Tags: swift, macos, nscombobox

I have the following code written in SWIFT for OS X App, the code is working fine (NSComboBox are select able only, not editable)

I have these two IBOutlet `projNewProjType` and `projNewRouter`, when I change the the selection of either of the NSComboBox, I can see the correct selected Index value and String value but how to check that the returned Index value is from `projNewProjType` NOT `projNewRouter` in the `comboBoxSelectionDidChange()`

```
import Cocoa
class NewProjectSetup: NSViewController, NSComboBoxDelegate {
  let comboxProjValue: [String] = [“No”,”Yes”]
  let comboxRouterValue: [String] = ["No","Yes"]

  @IBOutlet weak var projNewProjType: NSComboBox!
  @IBOutlet weak var projNewRouter: NSComboBox!


  @IBAction func btnAddNewProject(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(“Add New Button Pressed!”)
  }

  @IBAction func btnCancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewController(self)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addComboxValue(comboxProjValue,projNewProjType)
    addComboxValue(comboxRouterValue,projNewRouter)

    self.projNewProjType.selectItemAtIndex(0)
    self.projNewRouter.selectItemAtIndex(0)

    self.projNewProjType.delegate = self
    self.projNewRouter.delegate = self
  }


  func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let comboBox: NSComboBox = (notification.object as? NSComboBox)!

    print("comboBox comboBox: \(comboBox)")
    /* This printed “<NSComboBox: 0x6000001e1a00>”*/

    print("comboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem: \(comboBox.objectValueOfSelectedItem)")
    /* This printed the correct selected String value */

    print("comboBox indexOfSelectedItem: \(comboBox.indexOfSelectedItem)")
    /* This printed the correct selected Index value */        
  }

  /* Add value to Combo box */
  func addComboxValue(myVal:[String],myObj:AnyObject){
    let myValno: Int = myVal.count
    for i in 0..<myValno{
        myObj.addItemWithObjectValue(myVal[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set identifiers to your NSComboBoxes in IB. Select your combo box and choose identity inspector and name identifier. Then you are able to do like this:

```
if comboBox.identifier == "someIdentifier" {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Ooop! I'm bad. I set my identifier to wrong section under the Accessibility section, that's explain why I see strange string [_NS: 179] when i tried to print .identifier. After I correct it and put it under the Identity section, now I can use the .identifier to check the selector. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You already know the addresses of your two NSComboBox outlets and you know the address of which NSComboBox caused that notification to trigger, so why not do something like:

```
func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    let comboBox: NSComboBox = (notification.object as? NSComboBox)!

    if comboBox == self.projNewProjType
    {
        print("selection changed via self.projNewProjType")
    }
    if comboBox == self.projNewRouter
    {
        print("selection changed via self.projNewRouter")
    }
```